# Этимология слова "весёлый"

Tags: этимология

Пожалуйста, подскажите происхождение слова *весёлый (весел)*.

Answer (score 1):

http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Vesel-2534.html

Если верить Фасмеру, то от индоевропейского корня vesu- . В латинском языке Vesu означает имя бога или светлых богов.  Отсюда Веста, весталки, Везувий.